# Как сделать git ignore по первым символам?

Tags: git, gitignore

Мне нужно добавить в список игнорирования git файлы, которые начинаются на "builder_table".

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
builder_table*
```

.....................................